# C# Receber Objetos Serializados em um WebMethod

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, desserialização, webmethods

Boa tarde, estou passando uma lista de objetos do JS para o C#, para um WebMethod, como parâmentro da função, qual tipo de parâmetros este deve ser?

Eu criei uma classe para receber os dados:

```
public class serializeItens {
    //Dados de itens
    public RowGrid [] sXmlItens { get; set; }

}

public class RowGrid {

    public decimal ItemID { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public string itemUnid { get; set; }
    public decimal itemQtd { get; set; }
    public decimal itemCust { get; set; }
    public string itemIL { get; set; }
    public string itemCentr { get; set; }
    public decimal itemSaldo { get; set; }

    public RowGrid() {
        ItemID = 0;
        itemName = string.Empty;
        itemUnid = string.Empty;
        itemQtd = 0;
        itemCust = 0;
        itemIL = string.Empty;
        itemCentr = string.Empty;
        itemSaldo = 0;

    }
}
```

Com exatamente os mesmos argumentos que estou passando no pelos JS..

```
var oItem = {
    Codig: 0,
    Desc: "",
    Unid: "KG",
    Quant: 0,
    Custo: 0,
    IL: "",
    Centro: "",
    Saldo: 0
}
itensList.push(oItem);
```

Porém quando a chamo o WebMethod via ajax:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static bool salvaReg(EstoqMov PoMov, serializeItens PsItens) {
```

Retorna a seguinte mensagem de erro:

*Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: O método de servidor 'salvaReg' falhou com o seguinte erro: System.InvalidOperationException-- O tipo 'Gradual.Web.serializeItens' não é suportado para desserialização de uma matriz.*

Comment: Como está sendo feita a sua chamada AJAX? Poderia postar o código?

Comment: Claro..
 PageMethods.salvaReg(oMov, itensList, salvaReg_cb);

Comment: Teria que ser a chamada ajax em si: `$.ajax(...`

Answer (score 4):

O seu javascript deve estar fazendo a chamada da forma errada.

Assumindo que esteja usando jQuery, faça assim:

```
var oItem = {
    Codig: 0,
    Desc: "",
    Unid: "KG",
    Quant: 0,
    Custo: 0,
    IL: "",
    Centro: "",
    Saldo: 0
}
itensList.push(oItem);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'servico.asmx/salvaReg',
    data: JSON.stringify({ PoMov: oMov, PsItens: { sXmlItens: itensList } }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // resultado
    }
});
```

Comment: Não é um servico, é um WebMethod...

Comment: É do `WebMethod` mesmo que estou falando, quando digo URL do serviço... mas vou colocar um exemplo, fictício, para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Bem melhor :) +1

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez: foi o William de Castro que fez a pergunta... mas até o momento ele não se manifestou.

Comment: @WilliamdeCastro A resposta atende às suas expectativas? Se sim, por favor, marque-a como aceita para o benefício da comunidade. Obrigado!